# Inversion of scalar field formula

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform

We know, the field solution  of the KG equation is given as
$$\phi(x) = \int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{2\omega} [a(k)e^{ikx} + a^\dagger(k)e^{-ikx}]$$

I want to invert this formula to get $a(k)$ in terms of $\phi(x)$.

It is explained but not fully solved in the Srednicki, section 3, page 40  as:

\begin{equation}
\int d^3x \ e^{-ikx}\phi(x)  =    \frac{1}{2\omega} a(k)+ \frac{1}{2\omega}a^\dagger(-k)e^{2i\omega t}
\end{equation}
similarly,
\begin{equation}
\int d^3x \ e^{-ikx}\partial_0\phi(x)  =    -\frac{i}{2} a(k)+ \frac{i}{2}a^\dagger(-k)e^{2i\omega t}
\end{equation}
now combine these to get,
$$a(k) =\int d^3x e^{-ikx} [i\partial_0 \phi(x) + \omega\phi(x)]$$

I just need the help how to we arrive at the second equation , i.e.,
\begin{equation}
\int d^3x \ e^{-ikx}\phi(x)  =    \frac{1}{2\omega} a(k)+ \frac{1}{2\omega}a^\dagger(-k)e^{2i\omega t}
\end{equation}
rest I can figure out using that. Please help.

Comment: You just plug in the definition of $\phi$ in terms of a and then integrate over both k,x firstly over x to get a Dirac delta in k  from the exponential and then to evaluate at k

Comment: You have to make use of a representation of the Dirac delta, which appears in Fourier integrals often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a plain inverse 3d Fourier transform, once you reverse your garbling of it:
$kx=\omega({\mathbf k}) t- {\mathbf k} \cdot {\mathbf x}$.

$$\phi(x) = \int \frac{d^3{\mathbf K}}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{2\omega} \left [ a({\mathbf K}) e^{i(\omega t-{\mathbf K }\cdot {\mathbf x})} 
 + a^\dagger({\mathbf K})e^{-i (\omega t-{\mathbf K }\cdot {\mathbf x})}\right ]\tag{3.19} \implies $$

$$
 e^{-i\omega({\mathbf k}) t}\int d^3{\mathbf  x} \ e^{i{\mathbf k }\cdot {\mathbf x}}\phi(x)  =    \frac{1}{2\omega} a( {\mathbf k})+ \frac{1}{2\omega}a^\dagger(-{\mathbf k})e^{2i\omega t}\tag{3.20}.
 $$

I assume you appreciate how the triple ${\mathbf x}$ integration gives you a 3d  $~~\delta({\mathbf K} \mp{\mathbf k} )$, respectively, for each term, centered  on *opposite* ${\mathbf k}$s, which then collapses (3.19) on $\pm{\mathbf k}$ as in (3.20). As a quadratic function of ${\mathbf k}$, $\omega$ is the very same for both cases—it doesn't care!